# making connections while creating blog via wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I'm fully new in these web staff .I just want to make a blog page.To do this, I purchased a domain and hosting. I've installed wordpress on my ubuntu based machine. So,here is my questions.

How could I connect my page with wordpress to add content to my blog

Should I install something else ? I dont do anything with Database altough I believe I should do.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. if someone could give me some cool tutorial I'll be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed your wordpress already then you can login to control dashboard by URL `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/`. There you can add posts to your blog.

Or I don't understood your question.